# Laravel 5.4 : API controller and methods

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-5.4

Suppose you have a `PostController` for your web part, Where you are returning your views etc, And you need an `Api` also, What will be the best place to put the logic for `Api`.

Is the `PostController` will have the `Api` methods, Or another `ApiPostController` will be good place ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinion based question, there is no correct answer.

Personally i place my API and web controllers into separate sub folders of the `controllers` folder, give them separate namespaces, and then in my route groups prefix the correct namespace.